# Writing error in Desfire Card

Tags: mifare

I create an application with one file.(file_id = 0×09)

I want to write 13(=0x0d ) bytes Data in that file .I used this command :

90 cd 00 00 14 09 00 00 00 0d 00 00 13 byte data 00

I receive 91 f0

91 f0 means FILE_NOT_FOUND While the if i create another file with file_id = 0×09

I receive 91 de (douplication eror )

Can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Desfire commands are organized into different categories. Writing data in a file, for example, is part of the data manipulation commands. At the beginning of any communication, you are at the PICC level. So prior to send the write command you must first select an application with the AID of this application.

The command, in wrapped APDU ISO 7816 format, to select an application is as followed:

```
cls  ins    p1   p2   lc [data] le
0x90 [0x5A] 0x00 0x00 lc [AID]  0x00
```

The command, in wrapped APDU ISO 7816 format, to write data in a file is as followed:

```
cls  ins    p1   p2   lc [data]                        le
0x90 [0x3D] 0x00 0x00 lc [fileNO,offset,length, data]  0x00
```

NB : Once you have selected an application, according to the settings of the file, an authentication and the creation of a session key may be required before being able to write data in this file.

Answer (score -1):

You have to first select the application in which this file exist and then select the file.